# Check that csv-header is correct

Tags: apache-nifi

Please help me understand this thing.
How organize check for correct of CSV-file header in NIFI.

I'm waiting CSV with header "c1, c2, c3".
But I received the file with header "c2, c3, c4"

Need:in dataflow-file set c1 field to null and send message to email that c4 data field is not needed...

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go this way:

```
GetFile -> Extract Text -> RouteOnAttribte -> UpdateAttribute
```

Where in extract text you can use regex, fetching you the first line with the header.